# trying to remove something from value using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like the value of the input to change when the checkbox is checked and unchecked.

I have it working so that when a box is checked the values of the unchecked boxes becomes

> "ATTPVAT2", "ATTPTAX2", "ATTPBHS2"

etc. but I am not sure how to set up the jquery so when a box is unchecked it removes the 2 and becomes

> "ATTPVAT", "ATTPTAX", "ATTPBHS"

again.

The line

```
var core2Name = $(".ATT:not(:checked)").val() - "2";
```

returns a NaN

```js
function core2() {
  var i = 0;

  $('.ATT').each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      i += 1
    }
  });
  $('.ATT').each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':not(:visible)')) {
      i += 1
    }
  });

  if (i < 0) {
    var core2Name = $(".ATT:not(:checked)").val() - "2";
    $(".ATT:not(:checked)").val(core2Name);

  };


  if (i == 1) {
    $(".ATT:checked").prop('disabled', true);
    var core2Name = $(".ATT:not(:checked)").val() + "2";
    $(".ATT:not(:checked)").val(core2Name);

  };

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="examlist" value="ATTPTAX" id="ATTPTAX1" class="ATT" onclick=" if(core2()){this.checked=false}; " />
<input type="checkbox" name="examlist" value="ATTPVAT" id="ATTPVAT2" class="ATT" onclick=" if(core2()){this.checked=false}; " />
<input type="checkbox" name="examlist" value="ATTPBHS" id="ATTPBHS3" class="ATT" onclick=" if(core2()){this.checked=false}; " />
```

Comment: Search for `replace` instead of `-`(minus)

Comment: `core2()` doesn't return anything, why do you use it in `if()`?

Comment: Please use the jQuery onload handler to assign the code to the checkboxes instead of inline

Comment: You really should use data attributes for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-` is for subtraction of numbers, it doesn't work with strings. You get `NaN` because `"ATTPVAT2"` isn't a number, so it doesn't make sense to perform arithmetic with it.

The function to remove a character from a string is `String.prototype.replace`. It should be:

```
var core2Name = $(".ATT:not(:checked)").val().replace('2', '');
```

Comment: or regex any number to remove from any checkbox

Answer (score -2):

You'r codesnipet is malformed, check if this can help you:

```js
function core2(chk) {
                var isChecked = $(chk).is(':checked');
                $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function(index, item) {
                  var name = $(item).attr("name");
                  var id = $(item).attr("name");
                  if (isChecked)
                    $(item).val(id);
                  else
                    $(item).val(name);
                });
        
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type = "checkbox" name="examlist"  value="ATTPTAX" id="ATTPTAX1"  class="ATT" onclick =" core2(this)" />

<input type = "checkbox" name="examlist"  value="ATTPVAT" id="ATTPVAT2"  class="ATT" onclick =" core2(this)" />

<input type = "checkbox" name="examlist"  value="ATTPBHS" id="ATTPBHS3"  class="ATT" onclick =" core2(this)" />
```

Comment: You can't use `-` to remove a character from a string. That's his main problem and you didn't fix it.

Comment: Also core2 does not return anything